# Деление списка по 2 элемента, с дублированием предыдущего

Tags: python, list

Как разделить список, на списки по два элемента, с дублированием предыдущего, например:

```
#На входе
Spisok1=[0,6,7,14] 

#На выходе
S1=[0,6]
S2=[6,7]
S3=[7,14]
```

.

```
#На входе
Spisok2=[0,2,9,15,17]

#На выходе
S1=[0,2]
S2=[2,9]
S3=[9,15]
S4=[15,17]
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, не используйте заглавные буквы в названиях переменных, это считается некорректным в python, заглавные буквы используются в названиях классов)

Comment: @Step1709, спасибо, постараюсь запомнить, писала в спешке(

Comment: Не за что, если что это не приведет к ошибкам в коде, просто такое правило хорошего тона, так сказать) @lostns

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Есть простой способ через `zip`, правда на выходе будет список кортежей:

```py
Spisok1=[0,6,7,14]
print(list(zip(Spisok1, Spisok1[1:])))
```

Вывод:

```
[(0, 6), (6, 7), (7, 14)]
```

Comment: спасибо большое! А как потом разбить их по два? Достать из кортежа?

Comment: Из списка в смысле? Кортежи внутри )  Ну типа такого: `s1, s2, s3 = zip(Spisok1, Spisok1[1:])`, но вообще нет смысла плодить однотипные переменные.

Answer (score 4):

Начиная с Python 3.10 в стандартном модуле `itertools` есть специальная функция для такого преобразования - [`pairwise`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.pairwise):

```
import itertools

spisok1=[0,6,7,14]
print(list(itertools.pairwise(spisok1)))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def qwe(s, *pisok):
    for x in pisok:
        yield [s, x]
        s = x
print(*qwe(0,2,9,15,17))  # [0, 2] [2, 9] [9, 15] [15, 17]
```

Comment: нравится ответ )